# How do I create resource packages with a filetype? NSBundles?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, nsbundle

I am not sure what it is called, but I'm looking for a way to create packages (a directory containing a bunch of non-executable files, i.e. images) with custom file extensions. For example, I want to create a theme package named `example.theme`, which contains a bunch of images. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a directory with that name. On iOS, there is no file manager, so you don't have to worry about it appearing as a bundle or just as a regular directory.